# Is it possible to hold member functions with different arguments in an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, function, oop

Suppose I have

```
void a::f1()
void a::f2(int)
void a::f3(const std::string&)
```

Is it possible for me to use an array to store something like

```
ary1 = {&a::f1, bind(&a::f2, 2), bind(&a::f3, "abc"}
ary2 = {&a::f1, bind(&a::f3, "def")}
```

Comment: the ones you want to store in the array dont have different arguments. Btw, yes it is possible

Comment: Sure, why not, but you are missing the placeholder for the this pointer

Comment: `std::function` comes to mind...

Comment: A handful of those ;) @StoryTeller

Comment: I tried this, but got error [link](http://cpp.sh/8guf)

Comment: `std::vector<std::function<void(a&)>>` ?

Comment: @MikeMB: Both should be acceptable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to store different callable objects in `std::function` as long as the callables have the same signature, e.g.:

```
struct A {
    void f1();
    void f2(int);
    void f3(const std::string&);
};

int main() {
    std::function<void(A&)> functions[] = {
          &A::f1
        , [](A& a) { a.f2(2); }
        , [](A& a) { a.f3("abc"); }
        , std::bind(&A::f3, std::placeholders::_1, "abc") 
    };

    A a;
    for(auto& f : functions)
        f(a);
}
```

Note that I used lambda expressions here instead of `std::bind` because lambdas are the best practice: easier to write, read and more efficient.

Comment: seems the OP's problem is related with *member* functions

Comment: @Gruffalo This solution _is_ for member functions.

Comment: @JosephThomson now it is :)